# iPhone 8 cannot connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: network, wifi

This is a new problem that happened to me today.

I cannot connect to my Wi-Fi on my iPhone 8 even though, in the **Settings**, it shows that I **am** connected to Wi-Fi. It does not show on the top left, and I can't use it either.

All my other devices connected to the Wi-Fi work.

Comment: Is the iPhone's software up to date? Have you tried a [forced restart](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios)?

Comment: It is not working after a forced restart... I might want to call my carrier. However it's only like that for my iPhone (not my mac) for some reason

Comment: Try your iPhone with another, different network. Does it connect correctly?

Comment: Yes... Although it does do some strange things such as scanning my touch ID but *not* unlocking the iPhone...

Comment: Assuming the phone's software is up-to-date (you didn't say), the next step is to completely erase and set up the phone as from new. Make sure the info on the phone is backed up beforehand, as doing this will erase _everything_ on the device. I don't know what version iOS your phone is running; in iOS 14.7.1, it's at Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. If that doesn't work, it's a hardware issue.

Comment: The software is *not* up-to-date because it sometimes drags down my phone's performance for some unnecessary features (to me). Therefore, I wouldn't want to update it, but I'll do it if there's no other way.